# How I can add multiple slashes in a url on Django

Tags: python, django, url

I have this url in my Django project:

```
url(r'^$', 'blog.views.index'),
```

When I go to mysite.com/ or mysite.com it works fine but I want to admit infinite slashes in the url like this:

mysite.com//////////////////////

mysite.com///

mysite.com///////

Comment: you should remove $ from end of you pattern and add something like this pattern : '[/]*' . but I'm not sure it work for you

Comment: It works but when i access to mysite.com/about it just load mysite.com/

Comment: ok , so you can add argument for your view that can handle urls.

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution that you can use in your project:

Update your urls to:

```
...
url(r'^(?P<defname>.*)$', 'blog.views.index'),
...
```

And this is simple views code:

```
import inspect
def index(request,defname=None):
    ## check if url was "/" without any defname
    if not defname:
        return HttpResponse("this is home page")

    ## check definition existence
    defname = locals()[defname]
    if not inspect.isfunction(defname):
        raise Http404()

    ## now run that definition
    return HttpResponse(defname())

def about():
    return "this is about us page"
```

Answer (score 0):

If MortezaIpo's suggestion worked

```
url(r'^[/]*', 'blog.views.index'),
```

but captured all urls, try moving it to the end of the url tuple.
Though this should be a better pattern.

```
url(r'^[/]*$', 'blog.views.index'),
```